# TORFL (Test of Russian as a Foreign Language) sample

Tags: узус, resources

Does anyone know where I can download sample TOFRL exams (Test of Russian as a Foreign Language)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search for TORFL (not TOF*R*L). For instance look [here](http://www.russian-test.com/eng/center/about_the_center). This is a site of "Центр подготовки и тестирования иностранных граждан по русскому языку при МГУ им. М. В. Ломоносова". Pages listed in *Levels of proficiency in Russian* have links to test examples.

Comment: @Artemix There is text only. I wonder if examples of audio are available.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov but the text example of what to be heard is there.

Comment: @Artemix, yes, but a listening certainly is not the same as a reading. There is no any clarity how quickly and legibly the speaker reads at a given level.

Comment: This is not a question about Russian language per se

Answer (score 1):

If you use torrent system I can advise you this link http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3897516 Here you can find tests for different levels

Comment: Disclaimer: this link points to a resource, which is more than likely infringes upon the copyright of the author of the referenced book.  I am not a copyright police - but be aware of it, as someone else may take an exception.

Comment: @user17629 If you find the answer here, on SE, helpful, it would be more appreciable to vote the answer up than thank the author in words.